# How do I split a M4B file provided I have a CUE file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, mp3

I have a large M4B file and a CUE file for it. I want to either split it into many M4B files, or split it into many MP3 files (former preferred).

I want to do this in the command line (OS X, but can use Linux if needed) and not install sketchy software. I have `ffmpeg` and can install other command line audio programs.

Answer (score 2):

There is 2-step process which I did and it worked well.

**Step 1 - Convert M4B to MP3**

For this, you can use VLC Media Player (not sure how to do via command line so here are the GUI instructions).

- Go to Media->Convert/Save
- Add the M4B file, click "Save/Convert"
- Under Profile, choose Audio-MP3
- Select the destination (output) file
- Press Start
- ...wait...but you should see a progress bar

**Step 1.5 - Fix missing tags**
Unfortunately, using VLC to convert the m4b to mp3 will remove all tags. So you might want to use something like puddletag (linux) to add the tags back in.

**Step 2 - Split the MP3 using the .cue file**

Once you have the MP3, use [mp3splt](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/mp3splt) (command-line)

The -c flag allows you to use the cue file for the split points.

Both of these are well worn programs (at least I have used both for years) so I do not think they are considered "sketchy."

Comment: Command line via ffmpeg: ffmpeg -i <INPUTFILE.m4b> <OUTPUTFILE.mp3> (when using ffmpeg, step 1.5 is no longer required)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how strict the CUE sheet format is, but assuming yours follows this general format:

```
TRACK 1 AUDIO
  TITLE "Chapter 01"
  INDEX 01 0:0:00
TRACK 2 AUDIO
  TITLE "Chapter 02"
  INDEX 01 22:56:01
```

then you can do this with ffmpeg and a perl one-liner.

```
user@host:~$ INFILE=input.m4b
user@host:~$ OUTPREFIX=output
user@host:~$ OUTEXT=mp3
user@host:~$ perl -ne 'sub p{printf(qq#"%s" -ss %f -to %f "%s_Chapter_%02d%s"\n#, "'"$INFILE"'", $_[0], $_[1], "'$OUTPREFIX'", $_[2], "'$OUTEXT'")}; if(/^\s+INDEX (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/){$a=$b;$b=$4/60+$2*60+$3; p($a, $b, ++$c)if$b>0}; END{p($b, $b*100, ++$c)}' CUEFILE.cue | xargs -n 6 ffmpeg -i
```

The perl one-liner ignores all lines in the cue sheet but the `INDEX ...` lines and also ignores the first index, assuming it is zero. It prints out arguments for ffmpeg. xargs takes the right number of arguments (6 at a time, in this case) and calls ffmpeg once for each chapter (or track, or whatever).

This method can be used with a cue sheet to split up and convert **any** audio/video file provided ffmpeg accepts the input and output file formats.

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful bit of code, but needed a couple of alterations to work for me. 'CUEFILE' is not set, but as it invariably has the same basename as the .m4d file, we can use that.
I also added a for loop to automatically convert all files in the dir.
Works well.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.m4b;
do
    INFILE=$i ;
    OUTPREFIX=$(basename "$i" .m4b) ;
    OUTEXT=.mp3 ;
    perl -ne 'sub p{printf(qq#"%s" -ss %f -to %f "%s_Chapter_%02d%s"\n#, "'"$INFILE"'", $_[0], $_[1], "'$OUTPREFIX'", $_[2], "'$OUTEXT'")}; if(/^\s+INDEX (\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)$/){$a=$b;$b=$4/60+$2*60+$3; p($a, $b, ++$c)if$b>0}; END{p($b, $b*100, ++$c)}' $OUTPREFIX.cue | xargs -n 6 ffmpeg -i
done;
```